Current Flow in N-Power MOSFET
How can current flow from source to drain in n-channel power MOSFET where the normal direction of N-channel MOS is drain to source?

Internal (External) diode ...

What's the context here? MOSFETs are in theory symmetrical devices and can be flipped with respect to the source and drain to provide similar performance (substrate connection notwithstanding). This is useful in reverse polarity protection applications where the body diode (as @Antonio51 mentions) would be an unwanted current path.

Two ways this can happen:

An inherent part of how n-channel MOSFETs are constructed is what is referred to as the body diode. The diode has a forward voltage drop (like all diodes), so there will be heat dissipation if too much current runs through it. As a result, it is generally not recommended for large currents, but it is OK for smaller currents.

When the MOSFET is on (gate to source voltage exceeds the threshold voltage), current can flow through the channel in either direction, usually with very little resistance.


Since n-channel MOSFETs are often used for low side switching purposes, current typically runs from drain to source, such that the MOSFET can be switched on and off by either applying a voltage at the gate or pulling the gate low. Due to the body diode, switching is not possible for currents running in the opposite direction, unless the voltage at the source is below the body diodes forward voltage.
Additionally, if there is a voltage at the source of an n-channel MOSFET, the gate to source voltage must be even higher to exceed the threshold voltage and fully turn on the MOSFET. This means a higher gate drive voltage is required to fully enhance the MOSFET channel when the source voltage is elevated.
